# Vim. Displaying register's content in a side bar

Tags: vimscript

I have written a vimscript for learning purposes. The script displays the content of registers in a side bar by polling all registers periodically and redrawing the side bar when any changes happens. I want to get a review.

My **Vim** version is **8.0**.

I know about the latest version and some features, which can be useful in this script, like [deletebufline()](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22997/14024), but I decided to stick to a more common version.

At this moment I use this script by such way:

1. Open source file `show_regs.vim`.
2. Do a `:so % | Showreg` command.

Also, it can be converted to a plugin and placed into an autoload directory I think.

The script is capable to execute three commands:

1. `Showreg` - creates the side bar
2. `Unshowreg` - removes the side bar
3. `Cleanregs` - cleans all numbered and lettered registers.

---

```
function! s:Update_reg_dict(timer)
    " If the register's bar was deleted manually,
    " stop update function's timer and remove all script's variables 
    if !buflisted(s:buf_name)
        call s:Unshow_reg_bar()
        return
    endif

    let l:flag = 0
    " The previous highlight dictionary should be discarded every time
    let s:highlght = {}

    " Comparison of current register values with stored in the dictionary
    for [l:key, l:val] in items(s:reg_dict)
        let l:new_val = strtrans(getreg(l:key))
        if l:val !=# l:new_val
            let s:reg_dict[l:key] = l:new_val
            " Adds a changed register to the highlight dictionary
            let s:highlght[l:key] = '*'
            let l:flag = 1
        endif
    endfor
    " if any register was changed, rewrite a bar
    if l:flag
        call s:Write_reg_dict_to_bar()
    endif
endfunction

function! s:Create_reg_bar()
    " if the register's bar doesn't exist
    if buflisted(s:buf_name)
        return
    endif

    execute 'rightbelow ' s:reg_bar_size.'vnew' s:buf_name

    set winfixwidth
    set nonu
    set nowrap

    " A changed registers highlight color
    highlight MyGroup ctermbg=green
    " Special characters colorizing
    highlight Escaped_chars ctermfg=blue

    call matchadd('MyGroup', '^\*".')
    call matchadd('Escaped_chars', '\^[\[ICWLPMV@H]')

    execute 'wincmd p'
endfunction

function! s:Write_reg_dict_to_bar()
    let l:num = 1
    for l:key in split(s:reg_names, '\zs')
        let l:val = s:reg_dict[l:key]
        if l:val != ''
            " If a register was changed, then put a mark '*' to the beginning of line
            let l:mark = get(s:highlght, l:key, ' ')
            call setbufline(s:buf_name, l:num, printf('%s"%s| %s', l:mark, l:key, l:val))
            let l:num += 1
        endif
    endfor
    " Clean up all unneeded lines, which are left from the previous update
    " vim 8.1 has a special delete function 'deletebufline()', but I use vim 8.0
    while l:num < len(s:reg_dict)
        call setbufline(s:buf_name, l:num, '')
        let l:num += 1
    endwhile

endfunction

function! s:Create_reg_dict()
    if exists('s:reg_dict')
        return
    endif

    let s:reg_dict = {}

    for l:char in split(s:reg_names[1:], '\zs')
        " 'strtrans' is used to make register content printable
        let s:reg_dict[l:char] = strtrans(getreg(l:char))
    endfor
    " Unnamed register should be treated separately
    let s:reg_dict['"'] = strtrans(getreg(''))
endfunction

function! s:Unshow_reg_bar()
    if !exists('s:reg_dict')
        return
    endif

    if buflisted(s:buf_name)
        execute 'bdelete!' s:buf_name
    endif

    call s:Timer_stop()
    " Cleaning up of script's variables scope
    for l:variable in keys(s:)
        execute 'unlet s:'.l:variable
    endfor

" Other way to clean
"       unlet s:buf_name
"       unlet s:reg_names
"       unlet s:reg_dict
"       unlet s:highlght
"       unlet s:timer
"       unlet s:reg_bar_size
"       unlet s:update_time
endfunction

function! s:Timer_start()
    let s:timer = timer_start(s:update_time, function('s:Update_reg_dict'), {'repeat': -1})
endfunction

function! s:Timer_stop()
    call timer_stop(s:timer)
endfunction

function! s:Clean_regs()
    if !exists('s:reg_dict')
        return
    endif

    " Only numbered and lettered registers are cleaned
    for l:char in split(s:reg_names[1:-7], '\zs')
        call setreg(l:char, '')
    endfor
endfunction

" Main function
function! s:Show_reg_bar(...)
    if exists('s:reg_dict')
        return
    endif

    let s:reg_bar_size = a:0 >= 1 ? a:1 : 30
    let s:update_time = 100
    let s:buf_name = 'reg_bar'
    let s:reg_names = '"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-.:%#/='
    let s:highlght = {}
    let s:timer = ''

    call s:Create_reg_bar()
    call s:Create_reg_dict()
    call s:Write_reg_dict_to_bar()
    call s:Timer_start()

endfunction

command! -nargs=* Showreg call s:Show_reg_bar(<f-args>)
command! Unshowreg call s:Unshow_reg_bar()
command! Cleanregs call s:Clean_regs()
```

**Demonstration**

[image]